# How long does text stay in Spotlight Search?

Tags: macos

[image]

The text you enter in Spotlight search stays there if you close it and reopen it, but it automatically disappears after some time limit. How long is such amount of time?

Comment: I feel like this is a bit of laziness. I mean can't you just time it yourself?

Comment: @JBis how do you time it ?

Answer (score 1):

Every time you reopen (to look at it) it the timer starts anew.

If you leave it closed, it will expire (refresh) after 5-10 minutes as I measured.